# Disabling caching for modified js file

Tags: extjs4

I have converted java script files to minifying java script files through build.
but I don't want caching of modified js file.
I have tried this

As i am converting java script file to minify version,minify version have same timestamp.I want timestamp of origional java script files which are modified and
append to minify version file so they will not be cahced.

Comment: Are you building using sencha app build ? Then you should not have that problem. Or does your server config force caching of Javascript files ?